# How to Remove Active css from woocommerce variation?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, jquery, select

I have a small pickle.
I can't figure out how to turn the css off after it gets activated.
If the user changes their mind, I want the yellow to turn off if they deselect the button (variation). I can't figure this out.

```
    $( ".variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_variation_select_change", function () {
    $(".ivpa_clicked").css("background-color", "yellow")
} );
 
$( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
    // Fired when the user selects all the required dropdowns / attributes
    // and a final variation is selected / shown
    $(".ivpa_clicked").css("background-color", "green")
} );
```

here's the page I'm working with:
https://testusers.newisw.com/product/girls-blazer/

Side Note: I tried this too, but no luck turning it off:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $  ( "form.variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_variation_select_change", function () {
 if ($(".ivpa_clicked").css("background-color", "yellow"));
    else if 
     ($ (".ivpa_clicked").css("background-color", "transparent !important"));
 }
   );
  });
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE!
Turns out, I could use or (hack into) the existing CSS from whatever plug-in I'm using, and change or modify the look of the CSS. This way the functionality stays the same, allowing me to simply “decorate” in CSS. Your plug-ins code may vary in technique from mine, but over all just find the existing code/class/script, whatever, and build off it.

So in the end, I did NOT use any of the code in my original posting.
In my case, the plugin I have used simple CSS to turn ON and OFF the variations, so I just tweaked my own look around it.